# Resolve not working in Angular ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to use a resolve to front-load data from Rates Service in my Controller (rates controller) and get a blank screen. The api works but for some reason when I go step by step, in the execution, it skips over the $http.get method within the service :-/. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this? Cheers!

**rates.contoller.js**

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular.module('print.module').controller('ratesCtrl', ['ratesTest123', function (ratesTest123) {
    console.log(ratesTest123);
}]
)})();
```

**rates.service.js**

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular.module('print.module').service('ratesService', ['$http', function ($http) {
    vm = this;

    function getRatesDataService() {
        console.log("test");
        return this.$http.get("api/Rates/GetRates");
    }

    //}
}]
)
})();
```

**print.module.js**

```
(function () {
"use strict";

var module = angular.module('print.module', [
    'ui.router',
]);
module.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/print');
    $stateProvider
        .state('print', {
            url: '/print',
            templateUrl: "Public/scripts/sharedViews/printNavbar.html"

        })
        .state('print.rates', {
            url: "/rates",
            controller: 'ratesCtrl',
            templateUrl: "Public/scripts/rates/rates.view.html",
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            resolve: {
                    ratesTest123: ['ratesService', '$q', function (ratesService, $q) {
                        var deferred = $q.defer();
                        ratesService.getRatesDataService().then(function (response) {
                            deferred.resolve(response.data);
                        });
                        return deferred.promise;
                     }]
                }
        })

   $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});

}());
```

**view (scripts tags only for reference)**

```
<body ng-app="print.module">
<div ui-view></div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.3.1/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>            
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/public/scripts/print.module.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/public/scripts/books/books.controller.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/public/scripts/terms/terms.controller.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/public/scripts/rates/rates.service.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/public/scripts/rates/rates.controller.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/public/scripts/services/modals.service.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assign the getRatesDataService function to your service

```
(function () {
 'use strict';

 angular.module('print.module').service('ratesService', ['$http', function ($http) {

    this.getRatesDataService = function () {
       console.log("test");
       return $http.get("api/Rates/GetRates");
    }

   //}
}]
)
} )();
```

since it returns a promise, you can simply do the following

```
    resolve: {
                ratesTest123: ['ratesService',  function (ratesService) {
                    return ratesService.getRatesDataService()
                 }]
            }
```